# Do I benefit from assigning skill points to both weapon sub-skills?

Tags: the-secret-world

When assigning skill points (SP) to weapons, I can put points in **Damage** and **Survivability** (slightly different between weapon types). In order to fulfill the SP requirement for being able to wield a weapon, points in either skill are sufficient.

How does this work exactly? If I would spend points on both sub-skills would I get both the damage and evasion boost? Or does only the higher one get used? Is it wise to fill them up both if you have the points (as a mainly tank role)?

[image: Blade skills]

Comment: You probably use two weapons so it is best when you bring one skill up to 10 of each weapon and from then on you can max out the second skill for both weapons. But i wouldnt level up both right away. For some weapons it even doesnt make sense because the skills refer to a ability group (like drones for pistols) you might not even be using.

Comment: @PatrickStalder - I have yet to see any QL10 items that actually require skill level 10, so you might be okay stopping at 9.  (I am not at endgame though so there might be some I haven't run into)

Comment: @Shinrai sure you can stack the points up until you need them, since the passive bonus gain seems pretty weak anyway. It might even be a good thing to do if you are not 100% sure whether you want to play a weapon or not for a longer period of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both bonuses get applied when using the weapon in question; it's purely a question of which one you want to prioritize.